# Как запретить выделение текста?

Tags: html, css

Как я могу запретить выделение текста в определенном элемента?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/18080/  вот

Comment: и на js решение: https://learn.javascript.ru/unselectable

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Кроссбраузерное](http://caniuse.com/#feat=user-select-none) решение:

```css
.unselectable {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;   /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
  -khtml-user-select: none;    /* Konqueror */
  -moz-user-select: none;      /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;       /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;           /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  not supported by any browser */
}
```

```html
<p>
  Selectable text.
</p>
<p class="unselectable">
  Unselectable text.
</p>
```

Больше информации **[здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select)**.

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы value в Input нельзя было выделить? из статьи на Хабре просто сразу говориться (кроме элементов INPUT и TEXTAREA)